# Java stackOverFlow error Objects aren't coded the right way

Tags: java, object, stack-overflow

I'm working on a project for shipping maps. I've created an object called Chart and an object called Pos for the position. What i can't get to work is that when i read te charts from a text file to create the object Pos correctly because that is where it fails.

Now here is the Pos Class

```
 private Pos Pos;

 public Pos(int d, int m, int t){
      Pos pos = new Pos(d,m,t);
 }
```

Now here is the Chart class

```
private String title;
private String colorString;
private String scale;
private String edition;
private Pos north;
private Pos south;
private Pos west;
private Pos east;

private Chart Chart;

public Chart(Pos north, Pos south, Pos west, Pos east, String color, String scale, String edition, String title){
    Chart = new Chart(north, south, west, east, color, scale, edition, title);
}
```

Now here is where i want the code to create charts. I've made a lot of small steps to make sure the output is correct:

```
In in;
    String fileName = "charts.txt";
    int aantalKaarten;
    int kolommen;
    String[][] tabel;
    int n1,n2,n3,s1,s2,s3,w1,w2,w3,e1,e2,e3;
    String color;
    String edition;
    String scale;
    String title;

    in = new In(fileName);
    aantalKaarten = in.readInt()+1;
    for(int i = 0;i < aantalKaarten;i++){
        try {
            n1 = in.readInt();
            n2 = in.readInt();
            n3 = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("Noordelijke lengtegraad: " + n1 + ", " + n2 + ", " + n3);
            s1 = in.readInt();
            s2 = in.readInt();
            s3 = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("Zuidelijke lengtegraad: " + s1 + ", " + s2 + ", " + s3);
            w1 = in.readInt();
            w2 = in.readInt();
            w3 = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("westelijke breedtegraad: " + w1 + ", " + w2 + ", " + w3);
            e1 = in.readInt();
            e2 = in.readInt();
            e3 = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("oostelijke breedtegraad: " + e1 + ", " + e2 + ", " + e3);
            color = in.readString();
            System.out.println("De kleur van de kaart: " + color);
            edition = in.readString();
            System.out.println("Editie: " + edition);
            scale = in.readString();
            System.out.println("Schaal: " + scale);
            title = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Kaart: " + title);
            System.out.println("");
            Pos north = new Pos(n1,n2,3);
            Pos south = new Pos(s1,s2,s3);
            Pos west = new Pos(w1,w2,w3);
            Pos east = new Pos(e1,e2,e3);
            Chart chart = new Chart(north, south, west, east, color, scale, edition, title);
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException eNSEE){
                System.out.println("No such element exception");
        }
    }
    in.close();
```

I'm really hoping i could get some help because i'm hopelessly stuck. Probaly the changes made to Pos i also have to alter to Chart because the build up is the same

Thanks in advance for the help.

edit:
This is the text file that i am processing

```
 20
 51 53 00 3 49 00 51 49 70 3 59 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 5
 51 53 00 3 59 00 51 49 70 4 09 15 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 6
 51 49 50 3 28 90 51 42 10 3 49 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 7-8
 51 49 50 3 49 00 51 42 10 4 09 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 9-10
 51 41 80 3 19 20 51 34 00 3 39 60 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 11-12
 51 42 20 3 39 40 51 34 40 3 59 70 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 13-14
 51 42 40 3 59 70 51 34 60 4 19 80 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 15-16
 51 42 60 4 19 60 51 34 80 4 29 80 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 17
 51 34 20 3 19 80 51 26 80 3 39 90 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 19-20
 51 34 60 3 39 80 51 26 80 4 00 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 21-22
 51 34 60 3 59 70 51 27 20 4 20 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 23-24
 51 26 70 3 20 00 51 19 00 3 40 20 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 25-26
 51 27 00 3 40 00 51 19 40 4 00 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 27-28
 51 27 15 4 00 00 51 19 60 4 20 20 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 29-30
 51 27 60 2 28 60 51 00 00 2 58 40 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.2
 51 32 00 2 51 60 51 13 70 3 36 00 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.3
 51 30 50 3 22 50 51 20 50 3 44 30 G ed:2012      1:50.000  Hydro 1801.4
 51 48 60 3 00 00 51 30 40 3 40 00 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.5
 52 00 06 3 23 00 51 42 40 4 07 20 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.6
 52 15 60 3 46 40 51 57 60 4 29 60 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.7
```

Comment: What `public Pos(int d, int m, int t){ Pos pos = new Pos(d,m,t);}` you think is suppose to do? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please check a tutorial about how to properly use constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
public Pos(int d, int m, int t){
  Pos pos = new Pos(d,m,t);
}
```

When this code run, it recursively call Pos contructor itself, so it will be stacked and call inner Pos() then StackoverFlowException would not be so strange.

Your class should be

```
class Pos {
    int d;
    int m;
    int t;

    public Pos(int d, int m, int t) {
       this.d = d;
       this.m = m;
       this.t = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast replies. Fixed the problems and learned a quite important bit. But what i still can't see to find out is that in the textfile are 20 charts. When i print them i only get 1 error which is NoSuchElementException but it doesn't do it with the previous charts.

Comment: you should post what is actually in your text file

Comment: I added the text file. But i think that all the lines are correct.

Comment: I'm not so sure what does `readString()` do, but I guest it may read all to the end of file, then after first `readString()`, there are no element to read next, so exception will be thrown.

Comment: readLine() read the last bit of the line. That is necessary because the name of the chart is at the end and Hydro and Anwb have different length of names. The B's and the G's stand for the color so this has to be a string. The scale is 1:50.000 so this must also be a readString() same as ed:2012.

Comment: But you need show your `readString` that, it should only read from `current` position to the `next space`. Your `readString` may return `B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 5` instead of `G`.
And if I was you, I first `readLine` to read all the line, then `split` it by the space, then I will fill the appropriate variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here, in your constructor it is calling itself, so there is a StackOverflowException

```
public Pos(int d, int m, int t){
     Pos pos = new Pos(d,m,t);<=here!
}
```